# Pressurization line (Helium to LOX tank line) chilling while pressurizing LOX tank

Tags: rockets, launch-vehicle, lox, helium, chilling

I have read that in rockets and launch vehicles Helium is used for the pressurization of propellant tanks.

What temperature Helium is stored at?

If Helium is stored at room temperature then while pressurizing does the pressurizing line is chilled through some mechanism so that the propellant tanks does not get affected?

Comment: The tanks for gaseous Helium were mounted within the LOX tank sometimes. No chilling was necessary then and more Helium may be loaded at the same maximum pressure.

Comment: @Uwe, so that means that at the time of filling we will be chilling the complete tank along with the helium tank inside?

Comment: I don't know the order of Helium and LOX loading but I think Helium was loaded before LOX. After chilling Helium may be toped off.

Comment: On shuttle the helium tanks weren't inside the prop tanks and they got *hot* during pressurizing.

Comment: The first stage of the Saturn V used Helium tanks inside the LOX tank. The third stage had spherical Helium tanks inside the LH2 tank. The diagram of the second stage did not show the location of the Helium tanks.

Comment: Helium tanks do get hot during pressurizing. That is true for Helium tanks inside and outside prop tanks. If you want to load helium first and wait for the tanks to cool down before loading cryogenics, you may have to wait a pretty long time.

Comment: @Uwe, i agree with your reasoning, but after the loading we can chill it along with the oxidizer tank chilling in case of internal helium tank, so no problem there. But what happens when we are keeping the helium tank outside and then using it for pressurization of the oxidizer tank, do we need chilling for that?

Comment: Shuttle kept the helium tanks outside and there was no active cooling of the tanks.  They got hot during filling and then slowly approached the ambient temperature. Don't forget shuttle used autogenous pressurization so hot gas tapped from the engines pressurized the tanks after liftoff. There was no attempt to cool it down, being hot helps!

Comment: @Amar why would the propellant tank get affected by the He gas? Also why should it be cool? In fact, check Chp 5 of Modern Engineering for design of Liquid propellant rocket engine, which discusses the use of heated Helium

Comment: @karthikeyan, won't the heated helium increase temperature of the whole system which leads to rapid conversion of liquid to gas and hence rapid increase in tank pressure?

Comment: @Amar Yes one of the trade off. Carry a lot ot He Vs carry little extra propellant. If time permits, I will try to add the calculations.